# Getting 403 Forbidden while using gate facade

Tags: laravel, laravel-facade

When writing privileges and rights of a user shows error: `403 Forbidden`

Controller code

```
class IndexController extends AdminController
{
    public function __construct(){

        parent::__construct();

        if (Gate::denies('VIEW_ADMIN')) {
            abort(403);
        }

        $this->template = env('THEME').'.admin.index';
 }
```

AuthServiceProvider code

```
public function boot()
{
    $this->registerPolicies();

   Gate::define('VIEW_ADMIN', function($user){
        return $user->canDo('VIEW_ADMIN');
    });

    //
}
```

Model User code

The `User` model is associated with the `Roles` model, and the `Roles` model is associated with the `Permission` model.

```
public function canDo($permission, $require = FALSE){

    if (is_array($permission)) {
        dump($permission);
    }
    else{
        foreach ($this->roles as $role) {
           foreach ($this->permissions as $permission) {
               if (str_is($permission,$permission->name)) {
                   return true;
               }
           }
        }
    }        
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `Gate` definition and registration appear to be fine, I suspect the error lies in your `canDo` function.

Ignoring the `if(is_array($permission))` check:

```
// does the user have any roles?
foreach ($this->roles as $role) {
    foreach ($this->permissions as $permission) {
        // what is str_is? It's not a PHP function
        if (str_is($permission, $permission->name)) { 
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Check if the `user` has any `roles`, if they do not then `canDo` will return empty and be considered `false`.

Not sure what `str_is` is? It's not a PHP function, did you mean something like [`strcasecmp`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strcasecmp.php) or maybe [`Str::is`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#method-str-is)?

I suspect there are no roles, as otherwise you wouldn't get a `403`, instead you would likely get a `Call to undefined function str_is()` error.